# Approaching row limit for hobby-dev database on Heroku app

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I just got an email from Heroku about my database nearing its row limit, but I'm confused because my database has almost nothing in it.

`heroku pg:info` returns the following:

```
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           1/20
PG Version:            10.18
Created:               2018-08-11 04:56 UTC
Data Size:             13.7 MB/1.00 GB (In compliance)
Tables:                14
Rows:                  7290/10000 (In compliance, close to row limit)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on:                postgresql-xxx-xxxxxx
```

The data size looks not wrong, but the rows for some reason are way over what I would expect. If I check my console and do a `Model.count` for everything, it doesn't even begin to approach 7290. Why is this happening, and is it possible (or even advisable) to *clear* some of these rows?

Comment: Have you considered contacting Heroku support?

Comment: You could run a query [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225) to get the row count for each table to see which one has so many more rows than you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "secret" rows were a ton of uncleared sessions that hadn't touched for a year or so. Deleting them solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edited.

There are a couple ways to check how many entries your database has:

1. The [Heroku Postgres data dashboard](https://data.heroku.com/datastores/) should show `X of 10,000`.
2. Running a Postgres query to get the row count for each table:

```
SELECT schemaname, relname, n_live_tup 
  FROM pg_stat_user_tables 
  ORDER BY n_live_tup DESC;
```

That should help you troubleshoot the entry count yourself. Your database may be storing sessions or other non-obvious things.

---

For those suggesting that you file support, you cannot get Heroku support for the free database. Trying to [create a ticket](https://help.heroku.com/n/3/heroku-postgres) led me to the below message from Heroku, which led me to this question.

> Technical support for Free applications is provided by the online community.
>
> For all programming related questions related to particular languages or frameworks, please visit the Stack Overflow community. Stack Overflow is a great place to get help from fellow Heroku users by searching thousands of previous questions or asking your own. For all questions related to the Heroku platform or specific Heroku products, please visit the Salesforce Stack Exchange community.
>
> Finally, documentation can be found in our Knowledge Base and DevCenter articles. Technical support is provided on all paid applications. Visit your Heroku Dashboard to upgrade to the Hobby Tier. Please note that any changes made to your account's billing status can take up to 30 minutes before this message is removed.

Comment: I found out what it was! It was expired session data. I just had to set up a rule to clear it out every few months. Might be the same for you?